# Unix programming

Tags: unix, sed

how to makes sure that every line has an EVEN number of characters by removing the last character of lines with and ODD number of characters.

i tried this but it doesn't work 
sed -n '/^.{}/p'

please help

Comment: You could simply truncate all lines to have length zero.  That would be pretty easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to count the newline?  In other words, does the line "foo\n" have 4 characters or 3?  Assuming that you want to truncate the trailing 'o' in that line, you could do:

```
$ perl -pe 'substr( $_, -2, 1 ) = "" unless length( $_ ) % 2'
```

And the obligatory awk solution:

```
awk '{ print substr( $0, 0, length - length % 2 )}'
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is the simplest way, but the first that comes to mind is

```
sed '/^\(..\)*.$/s/.$//'
```

The `/^\(..\)*.$/` finds lines with an odd number of characters. The following `s` command only acts on those lines. `s/.$//` deletes the last character of each line it acts on (the ones with an odd number of characters).